# General term of the sequence $1,3,6,\ldots$ and $2,4,7,\ldots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Problem:** Find the general term of the sequence $1,3,6,10,15,21,\ldots$. Hence find the general term of the sequence $2,4,7,11,16,22,\ldots$.

**My work:** I found the term for $1,3,6,\ldots$ but I couldn't determine the term for $2,4,7,\ldots$. Please help me find the term.

Answer (score 4):

If you were able to find the general term for the first sequence (let's call it $a_n$) of numbers, then I have a hard time imagining you could not come up with the general term for the other sequence (let's call it $b_n$), simply because it is every term in the first sequence with $1$ added to it.

Thus, if you **truly** cannot figure it out, then consider this:

> $$a_n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ and $$b_n=a_n+1=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+1=\frac{n^2+n+2}{2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

The general term for the first (triangular numbers) is $T_n = \frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$ where $n$ begins from $1$.

The second sequence appears to have terms that are formed just by adding one to the triangular numbers. So you can just add $1$ to the general term to get $T_n = \frac{1}{2}n(n+1) + 1$

Answer (score 0):

$\lbrace a_n \rbrace= 1,3,6,10,15,21,\dots \Rightarrow \text{for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, }a_n=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and

$\lbrace b_n \rbrace= 2,4,7,11,16,22,\dots \Rightarrow \text{for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, }b_n=a_n+1$